# Excel VBA - If condition on image

Tags: excel, vba

I have added my macro to my toolbar and would like to put some sort of basic check on it. Instead of asking the user whether he wants to perform the macro, I would like to check the document for a certain image that is always in the documents the macro is used for. (other suggestions are welcome too)

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture -767")).Select
```

That's the code I use to select the image. I haven't been able to find out how to manage an image. What I'm trying to do is

```
If Image is found then
    Part1
    Part2
Else
    MsgBox 'Macro is not intended for this document'
End if
```

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PicTest()
Dim Shp As Shape

    On Error GoTo ErrorExit
    Set Shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture -767")
    On Error GoTo 0

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture -767")).Select
    Part1
    Part2
    Exit Sub

ErrorExit:
    MsgBox "Macro is not intended for this sheet"
End Sub
```

Comment: In your VBA go to TOOLS > OPTIONS > EDITOR > [x] Auto Syntax Check, turn that on.  This will put OPTION EXPLICIT at the top of any new modules you open/add.  You can add it manually to existing modules.  OPTION EXPLICIT is essentially "code checker", it forces you to declare all variables and checks your use of them AND points out a majority of spelling and code errors as you make them. This will save you hours of debugging over time.  OK?

Comment: That answer is good for you? Are you going to close out this thread?